# Install usblib package - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, libusb, pkg-config

I need the package libusb for another package I am installing.

I tried the following which seemed to install the package,

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev
```

but when I try to install the other package I get,

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libusb-1.0 >= 0.9.1) were not met:

No package 'libusb-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBUSB_CFLAGS
and LIBUSB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

When I run the command dpkg -L libusb-dev, I get:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/libusb-config
/usr/include
/usr/include/usb.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libusb.a
/usr/lib/libusb.la
/usr/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libusb.pc
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/index.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/preface.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/intro.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/intro-overview.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/intro-support.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-device-interfaces.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-timeouts.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-types.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-synchronous.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/api-return-values.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/functions.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.core.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbinit.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbfindbusses.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbfinddevices.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetbusses.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.deviceops.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbopen.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbclose.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbsetconfiguration.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbsetaltinterface.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbresetep.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbclearhalt.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbreset.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbclaiminterface.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbreleaseinterface.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.control.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbcontrolmsg.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetstring.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetstringsimple.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetdescriptor.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetdescriptorbyendpoint.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.bulk.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbbulkwrite.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbbulkread.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.interrupt.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbinterruptwrite.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbinterruptread.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/ref.nonportable.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbgetdrivernp.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/function.usbdetachkerneldrivernp.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/examples.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/examples-code.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/examples-tests.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/html/examples-other.html
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc-base
/usr/share/doc-base/libusb-dev
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/libusb-config.1.gz
/usr/lib/libusb.so
/usr/share/doc/libusb-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Thanks for the help, hope it was worth the -1.

Comment: @Antoine, There are plenty of comments out there about installation problems people are having. It's a stepping stone that all programmers take in order to be able to program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit of reading ... http://www.libusb.org/wiki/libusb-1.0#libusb-0.1

It appears, that the 0.1 and 1.0 series of the library are fundamentally different. A number of Linux distributions keep shipping the 0.1 series primarily, while an 1.x version can be installed additionally in parallel. You're looking for a package called `libusb-1.0` and corresponding development packages: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libusb-1.0-0 and http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libusb-1.0-0-dev